# How do the Durable and Dwarven Fortitude feats interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, healing, hit-points, hit-dice

How do the Durable and Dwarven Fortitude feats interact?

While the Durable feat (PHB, p. 166) states that you gain a minimum of double your Constitution modifier from using your Hit Dice to heal, the Dwarven Fortitude feat (XGtE, p. 74) has you regain Hit Points equal to what you roll, plus your Constitution Modifier, whenever you take the Dodge Action.

Since the Dwarven Fortitude feat has a more specific rule in regards to healing with Hit Dice, I was curious whether the two actually worked together properly.

Comment: Related: "[How does the Durable Feat work](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57522/how-does-the-durable-feat-work)"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## You would heal at least the minimum amount that Durable grants while using Dwarven Fortitude.

The [Durable](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/durable) feat says (PHB, p. 166):

> When you **roll a Hit Die to regain hit points**, the minimum number of hit points you regain from the roll equals twice your Constitution modifier (minimum of 2).

While the [Dwarven Fortitude](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/dwarven-fortitude) racial feat says (XGtE, p. 74; emphasis mine):

> Whenever you take the Dodge action in combat, you can **spend one Hit Die** to heal yourself. **Roll the die**, add your Constitution modifier, and regain a number of hit points equal to the total (minimum of 1).

Because DF says you roll the spent Hit Die, it counts as rolling a Hit Die to regain points, so Durable would apply.